# Templates not loading static files

Tags: css, django, templates, django-templates

I have a problem with loading the css file, after calling index.html who inherits base_ownsite.html which reads css page, css is not loaded...

base_ownsite.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ownsite/css/style.css' %}" />

</head>
<body>
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'ownsite/base_ownsite.html' %}


{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Jesteś zalogowany <a href='accounts/my_view'>{{ user.username }}</a></p>
    <p><a href='/accounts/logout_view'>wyloguj</a></p>

{% else %}
    <h2>Strona główna</h2>
<a href='/accounts/login_view'>logowanie</a>
<a href='/accounts/register_user'>rejestracja</a>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

style.css

```
body {
    background: yellow;
}

h2 {
    color: red;
}

p {
    color: yellow;
    }
```

settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/ownsite/static",
)
```

I add printscreen of my directories

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFeI8.png)

Comment: There's a whitespace (see underscored char) ``/css_/style`` in your code

Comment: Hmm in css I don't se this whitespace in <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ownsite/css/style.css' %}" /> "ownsite is underscored but I don't know why, there isn't any whitespace :/...

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode urls, your problem may be in STATICFILES_DIRS, change it to:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

also make sure that you have

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

at the top of your file

Comment: I set it like You advise and it want help. Also is strange, I replace this path to app style.css and it show this style but when I change something in this style.css it all the time see this style.css before changed. I also create file in another name like a.css and it is ok, I do some changes and page see it...But I don't understand why in project static folder and app style.css it not work correctly :/

Comment: Where do you keep your static files? is it in app folder or root? Just create static folder in root of your project and then create folder ownsite/css/ in there and place style.css in there